# pthreads SIGEV_THREAD and async-safe function calls

Tags: pthreads, signals

Having trouble tracking down answer to usage of SIGEV_THREAD...

When one sets SIGEV_THREAD as the notify method in sigevent struct, is it correct to assume that async-signal-safe functions must still be used within the notify_function to be invoked as the handler?

Also - is it correct to assume the thread is run as "detached"?

For example

notify thread

```
void my_thread(union sigval my_data)
{
    // is this ok or not (two non async-signal-safe functions)?
    printf("in the notify function\n");
    mq_send();
}
```

main function

```
(...)
se.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
se.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &my_data;
se.sigev_notify_function = my_thread;
se.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
(...)
```

Please provide a reference if possible.

Comment: "*asynch-save*" in the sense of "*asnch-signal-save*"? If yes: No.

Comment: @alk - do you have any reference?

Comment: Please see *caf*'s answer below.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need to use only async-signal-safe functions, because POSIX does not place any such limitation on the `SIGEV_THREAD` function.  (The whole point of `SIGEV_THREAD` is that it lets you handle asychronous notifications in a less constrained environment than a signal handler).

As far as the thread being detached, POSIX says:

> The function shall be executed in an environment as if it were the
>   start_routine for a newly created thread with thread attributes
>   specified by `sigev_notify_attributes`. If `sigev_notify_attributes`
>   is `NULL`, the behavior shall be as if the thread were created with
>   the detachstate attribute set to `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED`. Supplying
>   an attributes structure with a detachstate attribute of
>   `PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE` results in undefined behavior. The signal
>   mask of this thread is implementation-defined.

This means: you must either leave `sigev_notify_attributes` as `NULL`, or set it to an attributes structure with the detachstate set to `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED` - in both cases the thread will be created detached.

Comment: For completeness: The quote in the answer above originates from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_02 (last paragraph)

Comment: Thanks - I guess I assumed the spec would have explicitly stated the async-signal-safe feature since it is quite specific about other features of the standard.   Also - the man page remarks caused me to question "safeness"..  Notify the process by invoking sigev_notify_function "as if" it were the start function of a new thread.

Comment: @user3618690: The "as if" is there because the thread doesn't have to actually be started at the time the event happens - the implementation can have the threads pre-started and waiting around for an event, then call into the `sigev_notify_function`.